# Better mapping JSON to objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm using [v4 sheets API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/sheets/v4.ts) from [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client), it returns a lot of data. Though I filter it using `fields` arguments, the structure of JSON is very complex. So to incorporate it into my logic, I flatten it. And it needs to be safe, I don't want any exceptions to be thrown.

This is how the **UNSAFE** version of the code looks:

```
const data = response.sheets[0].data;
const columns = data.map((column) => {
  const rowData = column.rowData;
  const values = rowData[0].values;
  return rowData.map((cellData) => cellData.values[0].userEnteredValue);
});
// ...
```

If JSON is invalid, an exception is inevitable. I don't want this. The problem is that to fix it, I should add plenty of `if`-s. This would make the code look ugly.

Let's summarize: Is there a way to map JSON into local objects safely and expressive (and preferably relying only on features of **ES6**)?

**UPDATE**

Let's add a little more context. This is a small insight how deep the JSON is, and all I need to map it to an array of strings ('1.06' is one of them).

```
{  
   "sheets":[  
      {  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "rowData":[  
                  {  
                     "values":[  
                        {  
                           "userEnteredValue":{  
                              "stringValue":"1.06"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems you've already discovered the `map` function so that should take care of nested traversal.

Comment: @Halcyon I'm a newbie in the JS world, I know about `map` from other languages, so there might be gaps.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/erictrinh/safe-access and https://medium.com/@chekofif/using-es6-s-proxy-for-safe-object-property-access-f42fa4380b2c

Comment: Thanks, now I see that there's no better way :)